# Google Maps Store Locator Search field for embedded map

Tags: google-maps

I've embedded a map on a clients site, with their various store locations, using the google saved maps technique: http://passportal.com.au/stockists So basically I don't want store the marker locations in a database, I'm just interested in using the marker positions on the saved map as seen in this demo: http://maps.google.com/help/maps/getmaps/plot-multi.html

I've seen it on plenty of sites and am wondering if there is an easy way to add a search field to find the closest marker to the users address. Something like this: http://www.victoriantextiles.com.au/store-locator

The closest I could find was a google gadget that allows you to type in directions: http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open&hl=en&gl=en&url=http://igwidgets.com/lig/gw/f/islk/89/slkm/ik/s/1329844/87/charles447/google-maps-driving-directions.xml

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, I use Google Maps API [Distance Matrix](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#distance_matrix) where I would pass in one origin - user's location and multiple destinations - our dealers. Then I sort the results by distance and take 3 closest to display in a list. Works pretty fast, however, I don't know how you'd achieve this without having some sort of database of your store addresses.

Comment: That sounds like a good solution if I was to use a database. I thought google might have an intuitive solution for my problem (without using a db), but maybe not.